# Paranoid an increment! counter may not be working properly

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Last week I implemented a **:view_count** integer column on a **Job** model. Today I was comparing stats between my site and Google analytics. The numbers for pageviews didn't agree (sometimes way off) and I am now paranoid that perhaps I flubbed this simple task.

One additional complication is some conditional logic in this action. I would be open to a better way of writing this whole action if anyone wants to suggest any changes.

```
  def show
    unless signed_in?
      redirect_to jobs_path, status: 301, if @job.end_date  < Time.zone.now.to_date
      @job.increment! :view_count unless @job.end_date  < Time.zone.now.to_date
    end
  end
```

After reviewing API docs, I thought about re-writing the following line to:

```
Job.increment_counter(:view_count, @job) unless @job.end_date  < Time.zone.now.to_date
```

**So then.**
1) Anything wrong jump out here?
2) Which is better to use: increment! or increment_counter.

I am using Postgres for the database. Any helpful suggestion or thoughts are appreciated.

**Note:** Using a **before_filter** on :show for @job = Job.find(params[:id])

Comment: Are your page views based per day? And were some days higher, some days lower? Or was it just a flat value that was different?

Comment: On the Job model pageviews increment from the time the record is created until it ends. For comparison, I set Google analytics to look at the same date ranges for some jobs. The numbers between the two were off in both directions. Sometimes Google had more, other times the view_count was higher.

Comment: hrm. Well I'm asking because I ran into an issue where Time.zone was giving me inaccurate timezone data so it would read as, say, 12:00 but it would be 12:00 the previous day. I doubt the issue is as simple as that however but it should be relatively easy to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does anything wrong jump out? Yes, `increment!` is all wrong and IMHO should not be used. Why do I say that? As usual with Rails, you have to read the source to see what's going on. This is what [`increment!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L245) does:

```
def increment!(attribute, by = 1)
  increment(attribute, by).update_attribute(attribute, self[attribute])
end
```

And what does `increment` do? [`increment`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L235) does this:

```
def increment(attribute, by = 1)
  self[attribute] ||= 0
  self[attribute] += by
  self
end
```

and [`update_attribute`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L177) does this:

```
def update_attribute(name, value)
  name = name.to_s
  raise ActiveRecordError, "#{name} is marked as readonly" if self.class.readonly_attributes.include?(name)
  send("#{name}=", value)
  save(:validate => false)
end
```

Unrolling that, we see that your `@job.increment! :view_count` is the same as this:

```
@job.view_count = (@job.view_count || 0) + 1
@job.save(:validate => false)
```

The race condition in here should be clear:

1. Process-1 loads `@job`.
2. Process-2 loads the same `@job`.
3. Process-1 increments the `@job.view_count` and writes it to the database.
4. Process-2 increments the `@job.view_count` and writes it to the database.

But Process-2 doesn't know that Process-1 incremented the `view_count` behind its back so Process-1's increment disappears. So yeah, `increment!` is pretty dumb and prone to data loss, I wouldn't use it for anything.

If you trace through [`increment_counter`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb#L102) you'll see that it is just a wrapper for [`update_counters`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb#L75). If you read `update_counters`, you'll see that it correctly lets the database do the work by simply telling the database to increment a column value with SQL that is more or less like this:

```
update t set c = c + 1 where id = x
```

That should be reliable.

Summary: forget that `increment!`, `decrement!`, `increment`, and `decrement!` exist and use `increment_counter` instead.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed response. You have given me some good information to read further. So then, based on this I answer, it sounds like this may be why I feel like my view_count number is inflated when compared to Google Analytics. (sometimes 2-3 times for same date range.) I will swap out for the increment_counter code I was going for.

Comment: Any advice on a cleaner way to deal with my conditional logic in this controller action? It feels like I overcomplicated it and that maybe I should try to be more Rubyish to achieve my goals.

Comment: I would expect using `increment!` to under-report hits. Are you sure that everyone is working in the same time zone? Are you sure that Google Analytics is counting the same things that your controller is?

Comment: I have the time zone set to EST. The increment counter is triggered by the SHOW action on the Job. I am comparing that to pageviews on the URL for the job in Google Analytics.

Comment: The counter is triggered when all the following occur: (1) the user hits the show action, (2) the user is logged in, (3) the date condition is met. Is Google Analytics using the same three conditions?

Comment: The counter is triggered UNLESS the user is signed_in. Jobs with an end_date in the past redirect and don't count. I compare Google Analytics pageviews for the specific URL for the same time frame the job was "active". Should be comparing the same thing. Non-signed in user pageviews for a specific date range.